# Remote PowerShell connection script works for exchange PS but not for windows PS

Tags: c#, vb.net, powershell, remote-access, runspace

I've written a function to interact with the Exchange Shell remotly. Now I want to use it for the normal Windows PS. So I changed the Shell Uri in `WSManConnectionInfo` to `http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell`.

The function looks now like this:

```
Public Function remotePowerShell(ByVal script as String)

    Dim newCred As PSCredential = DirectCast(Nothing, PSCredential)
    Dim connectionInfo As New WSManConnectionInfo(New Uri("http://SVR2012R2-File/powershell?serializationLevel=Full"), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell", newCred)
    Dim runspace As Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo)
    connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Default
    Dim powershell As PowerShell = powershell.Create()

    Dim command As New PSCommand()

    command.AddScript(script)
    powershell.Commands = command

    Try

        runspace.Open()
        powershell.Runspace = runspace
        Dim psresult As New System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of PSObject)
        psresult = powershell.Invoke()
        For Each i In psresult
            MsgBox(vbNewLine & i.ToString)
        Next i

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox(Err.Number & vbNewLine & ex.Message)

    Finally

        runspace.Dispose()
        runspace = Nothing

        powershell.Dispose()
        powershell = Nothing

    End Try

End Function
```

If I run this function now I get the error:

> The WS-Management service cannot process the request. The resource URI
>   (http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell) was no
>   found in the WS-Management catalog. The catalog contains the metadata
>   that describes resource, or logical endpoints.

The function looks now pretty much the same like others of the same kind on SO, CodeProject and MSDN. The ShellUri is correct too.

I then tried another form of `WSManConnectionInfo`

```
Dim connectionInfo As New WSManConnectionInfo & _
(False, "SVR2012R2-File", 5985, "/wsman", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell", newCred)
```

Sadly this didn't work either.

I turned off both firewalls (from the Client and Memberserver) and restarted all related services I could think of (RPC, IIS, WS-Management)
This shouldn't be a problem anyway as the script works for interaction with the Exchange PS.

Is it possible that I need to define something more or do I need other `PSCredentials` ?

Thanks in advance for any shared thoughts.

Comment: Http won't work, because the http://servername/powershell website is installed by the exchange setup routine on Exchange Server (2010+).

Comment: @Martin which other Shell Uri should I use then? According to multiple posts like (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee309368(v=vs.85).aspx) it's the correct one.